# Play framework doesn't show image after upload in dist mode

Tags: playframework-2.0

I tried to upload image and view that image . It runs perfectly in development mode but in Production mode image uploads successfully but it doesn't display that image

To upload image I wrote :

```
    String sName=dStudent.studentName.replaceAll("\\s+",""); 
  String image_name = sName+sID+"_image.png";
     String contentType = student_image.getContentType(); 
     File file_type = student_image.getFile();

     try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(file_type, new File("public/photos/student", image_name));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Problem operating on filesystem");
        }
```

and to show that image I wrote :

```
<img src=@routes.Assets.at("photos/student/"+student.name.replaceAll("\\s+","")+student.sid+"_image.png") alt="" title="" width="200px" height="200px" border="0" style="margin-left: 18px;"/></span>
```

I created a separate Public folder on Dist mode to store those images . 
Can anyone help me out on this issue ? 
I used PLAY 2.1.3 for this .